# CosmosDB - return list with Top 1 of each item in a list with many records

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following table:

```
Id | Plate | RecordedAt
```

For each different plate there can be N records.

I'm struggling with  the following query:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 * 
 FROM table
 WHERE table.Plate IN ('plate1', 'plate2', 'plate3') 
 ORDER BY c.Recordedat DESC
```

The problem is that this query returns only 1 record with the last `Recordedat` item.

I need the last `Recordedat` of each item in the list.

Is there any way to achieve this with only one query?

For example for the following records:

```
Id  |     Plate    | RecordedAt
 1  |   Plate1     | 2021/09/26 6:53:06
 3  |   Plate2     | 2021/09/25 7:45:10
 4  |   Plate3     | 2021/09/23 02:10:42
 5  |   Plate1     | 2021/09/25 02:40:02
 6  |   Plate2     | 2021/09/26 15:14:02
 7  |   Plate1     | 2021/09/26 01:02:04
 8  |   Plate3     | 2021/09/26 16:02:20 
 9  |   Plate1     | 2021/09/24 05:02:20
 10 |   Plate2     | 2021/09/24 04:03:02
```

I need to return:

```
[
  {
    "Plate1":"2021/09/26 15:14:02"
  },
  {
    "Plate2":"2021/09/26 15:14:02"
  },
  {
    "Plate3":"2021/09/26 16:02:20"
  },
]
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that you are trying to query, just a few documents.

Comment: I've edited the post to add some records and the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` to group on the plates. Then you can use aggregate functions on the other columns. In this case you want the last/highest date so you can use `MAX`:

```sql
SELECT c.Plate, MAX(c.Recordedat) AS Recordedat
FROM c
WHERE c.Plate IN ('plate1', 'plate2', 'plate3') 
GROUP BY c.Plate
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do this type of query in Cosmos DB.

You will need to materialize the aggregate or value for each plate and then query for that.

Comment: ahhh okey, yes I imaged that thank you

Comment: I've edited the question to add some example data and the expected result, do you confirm that is imposible what i'm trying to achieve?